# Run a code only on theme activation only during first activation

Tags: php, functions, hooks, user-registration

```
function clearwidgets(){
  //stuff here only runs once, when the theme is activated for the 1st time
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'clearwidgets');
```

And the code I am trying to execute is this:

```
    add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'unset_sidebar_widget' );

function unset_sidebar_widget( $sidebars_widgets ) {
unset( $sidebars_widgets[ '$sidebar_id' ] );
return $sidebars_widgets;
}
```

That means when the first time the theme is installed it should clear away all the default widget set by WordPress.

Where am I going wrong because the desired result is not achieved? Please suggest me the fix or direct me in the direction so that I can troubleshoot.

Comment: are you trying to remove some available default widget options or clear the existing widget instances saved to existing theme sidebars? because the 2nd is unnecessary I am guessing it is the first?

Comment: `register_activation_hook()` is only for plugin activation. To handle activation of themes, use the [`after_switch_theme`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_switch_theme/) hook. With regards to widgets, how do you know they're the default? I suggest leaving people's content alone when activating your theme. If you want to show of what your theme can look like, consider using the Starter Content feature: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/30/starter-content-for-themes-in-4-7/

Comment: No when you install any theme for the first time. WordPress throw its default widgets in the posts sidebar(single posts). I want to get rid of them during theme's first activation.

Comment: Can you suggest final corrected code to achieve what i am trying 2 achieve?

Comment: "how do you know they're the default? " thats why I want to do this only once when the theme is activated for the first time?

Comment: How do you know that your theme is the first one that’s activated? Or that the user hasn’t modified the default widgets to their liking? Activating a theme should not mess with content.

Comment: whenever "my theme" is activated first time on any domain/subdomain or any URL it should unset previously existing widgets in the sidebar. Just once.

Comment: Try update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', array() ); on "after_theme_setup".

Answer (score 2):

What about using WordPress Options API to store a flag whether it is the first switch or not:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API

```
<?php
  add_action('after_switch_theme', 'setup_theme_options');

  function setup_theme_options () {
    if(get_option('first_theme_activation') === false){
      // Set a flag if the theme activation happened
      add_option('first_theme_activation', true, '', false);

      // stuff here only runs once, when the theme is activated for the 1st time
    }
  }
```

Going back to Jacob Peattie's note, `register_activation_hook()` is for plugin use and not for theme switching. And unsetting content could become tricky, because you don't know what is there.

Either way, I hope this answers helps!

Comment: This is thought provoking____